# Comparing an object and an array in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an array  as

```
R1_val_Y = [ [ '' ],
  [ 'suboption name2-charge1-Monthly-10' ],
  [ 'suboption name3-charge2-Monthly-10' ],
  [ '' ],
  [ '' ],
  [ '' ],
  [ '' ],
  [ '' ],
  [ '' ],
  [ '' ],
  [ '' ],
  [ '' ],
  [ '' ],
  [ '' ],
  [ '' ] ]
```

and an object as

```
R1_val_strikethrough_Y =
{ 'suboption name2-charge1-Monthly-10': 'Y14',
  'suboption name3-charge2-Monthly-10': 'Y15',
  'text1-text2-text3-text4: 'Y28' }
```

I want the mismatched entries from both `R1_val_Y` and `R1_val_strikethrough_Y` to be removed from `R1_val_strikethrough_Y`

I did try the below codes -

```
var keys1 = Object.keys(R1_strikethrough_check_Y);
   console.log(keys1);
  for (var k in R1_val_Y){
    if(R1_val_Y[k][0] != keys[k]){
      delete R1_strikethrough_check_Y[keys[k]];
    }
  }
```

Also tried ,

```
for (var i = 0; i < R1_val_Y.length; i++) {
    var entry = R1_val_Y[i][0];
    if (entry !== '') {
      if (!R1_strikethrough_check_Y.hasOwnProperty(entry)) {
        continue;
      }
      delete R1_strikethrough_check_Y[entry];
    }
  }
```

but did not get expected output.

The output to be as-

```
R1_val_strikethrough_Y =
{ 'suboption name2-charge1-Monthly-10': 'Y14',
  'suboption name3-charge2-Monthly-10': 'Y15' }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve it? Please don't just post code here and expect us to solve your problems for you...

Comment: Thank you @Markus Safar, I updated the question with what I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function myfunk() {
  let x = [[''], ['suboption name2-charge1-Monthly-10'], ['suboption name3-charge2-Monthly-10'], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''],
  [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], ['']].flat().filter(e => e);
  let y = { 'suboption name2-charge1-Monthly-10': 'Y14', 'suboption name3-charge2-Monthly-10': 'Y15', 'text1-text2-text3-text4': 'Y28' };
  Object.keys(y).forEach((p => {
    if (!~x.indexOf(p)) {
      delete y[p];
    }
  }));
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(y));
}

Execution log
12:22:48 PM Notice  Execution started
12:22:48 PM Info    {"suboption name2-charge1-Monthly-10":"Y14","suboption name3-charge2-Monthly-10":"Y15"}
12:22:50 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution to your question.

**Code.gs**

```
function test2() {
  try {
    let R1_val_Y = [  [ '' ],
                      [ 'suboption name2-charge1-Monthly-10' ],
                      [ 'suboption name3-charge2-Monthly-10' ],
                      [ '' ],
                      [ '' ],
                      [ '' ],
                      [ '' ],
                      [ '' ],
                      [ '' ],
                      [ '' ],
                      [ '' ],
                      [ '' ],
                      [ '' ],
                      [ '' ],
                      [ '' ] ];
    let R1_val_strikethrough_Y = {  'suboption name2-charge1-Monthly-10': 'Y14',
                                    'suboption name3-charge2-Monthly-10': 'Y15',
                                    'text1-text2-text3-text4': 'Y28' };
    R1_val_Y = R1_val_Y.filter( y => y[0] !== '' ).flat();
    console.log(R1_val_Y);
    let results = [];
    for( key in R1_val_strikethrough_Y ) {
      if( R1_val_Y.includes(key) ) results[key] = R1_val_strikethrough_Y[key];
    }
    console.log(results);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
11:29:15 AM Notice  Execution started
11:29:15 AM Info    [ 'suboption name2-charge1-Monthly-10',
  'suboption name3-charge2-Monthly-10' ]
11:29:15 AM Info    [ 'suboption name2-charge1-Monthly-10': 'Y14',
  'suboption name3-charge2-Monthly-10': 'Y15' ]
11:29:15 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Array.filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)
- [Array.flat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_array_flat.asp)
- [Array.includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp)
- [Arrow function =>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)